# How to use try catch to call graph api?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-graph-api

The current code uses then and catch to make a request to the GRAPH API. I want to change it to try and catch, how do I do it? Help me please.

Current code

```
import { loginRequest, graphConfig } from "../authConfig";
import { msalInstance } from "../main";

export async function callMsGraph() {
    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called.");
    }

    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: account
    });

    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

//graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample to use try catch in graph API,

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    return await fetch(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, options);
  } 
 catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // You might send an exception to your error tracker 
    return error;
  }
};
```

Hope this helps

Thanks